# JSON deserialization not deserializing?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am bit new to the serialization/deserialization of JSON's strings. I have tried to use *Newtonsoft.Json*. The thing is I got JSON string received from 
url : http://epguides.frecar.no/show/gameofthrones/ and I would like to create and class objects from it. So later I could print it out...

I found out how to generate classes from your JSON string, by copying the string and *Edit>Paste_Special>Paste_JSON_as_Classes* so that should be alright.

Generated classes:

```
namespace TvSeries
{

public class Show
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string imdb_id { get; set; }
    public string epguide_name { get; set; }
}

public class __invalid_type__1
{
    public Show show { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public int season { get; set; }
    public string release_date { get; set; }
}

public class Show2
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string imdb_id { get; set; }
    public string epguide_name { get; set; }
}

public class __invalid_type__2
{
    public Show2 show { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public int season { get; set; }
    public string release_date { get; set; }
}

public class Show3
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string imdb_id { get; set; }
    public string epguide_name { get; set; }
}

public class __invalid_type__3
{
    public Show3 show { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public int season { get; set; }
    public string release_date { get; set; }
}

public class Show4
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string imdb_id { get; set; }
    public string epguide_name { get; set; }
}

public class __invalid_type__4
{
    public Show4 show { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public int season { get; set; }
    public string release_date { get; set; }
}

public class Show5
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string imdb_id { get; set; }
    public string epguide_name { get; set; }
}

public class __invalid_type__5
{
    public Show5 show { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public int season { get; set; }
    public string release_date { get; set; }
}

public class Show6
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string imdb_id { get; set; }
    public string epguide_name { get; set; }
}

public class __invalid_type__6
{
    public Show6 show { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public int season { get; set; }
    public string release_date { get; set; }
}

public class Show7
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string imdb_id { get; set; }
    public string epguide_name { get; set; }
}

public class __invalid_type__7
{
    public Show7 show { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public int season { get; set; }
    public string release_date { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<__invalid_type__1> __invalid_name__1 { get; set; }
    public List<__invalid_type__2> __invalid_name__2 { get; set; }
    public List<__invalid_type__3> __invalid_name__3 { get; set; }
    public List<__invalid_type__4> __invalid_name__4 { get; set; }
    public List<__invalid_type__5> __invalid_name__5 { get; set; }
    public List<__invalid_type__6> __invalid_name__6 { get; set; }
    public List<__invalid_type__7> __invalid_name__7 { get; set; }
}

}
```

Here is simple main class to print it out to the console:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TvSeries
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                var json = wc.DownloadString("http://epguides.frecar.no/show/gameofthrones/");
                //Console.WriteLine(json);
                RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
                foreach (var item in obj.__invalid_name__1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Show: {0}, release date: {1}", item.show.title, item.release_date);
                } 
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the actual question is why is not deserializing or working properly, because the objects are still *null*? I am missing something important? I have also tried *JavaScriptSerializer()* but it doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: you have a whole load of classes with different names that are the same (show1 / show2 etc). this is created rather stupidly by vs because the json you pasted from returns a list of show's and for each list element, vs has created a different class for it. simplify the classes. also i assume "invalid type" classes are for an `Episode`. tidy up the classes and jsonconvert will automatically fill your objects as you expect. It's currently returning null because it's failing to deserialize.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with the data, you may even get away with deserializing into a `dynamic` object without generating the classes at all.

Comment: Did you not notice you have a bunch of types named `__invalid_type__n`? That should give you an indication.

Answer (score 0):

You use an attribute like this:

```
[JsonProperty("show")]
public Show2 Show2 { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As user3791372 said, you should tidy up the generated classes. However these classes where generated because the response looks like this
{ "1":[{...}...], "2":[{...}...],...}. So you first need to get rid of "1", "2" and define your own types for clean code. the result will look like this

```
class Show
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string imdb_id { get; set; }
    public string epguide_name { get; set; }
}

class Episode
{
    public Show show { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public int season { get; set; }
    public DateTime release_date { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            //download json string
            var json = wc.DownloadString("http://epguides.frecar.no/show/gameofthrones/");
            //convert json to dynamic object
            JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
            //create an array that have as many elements as the children of obj => {"1", "2", "3", ...}
            JArray[] results = new JArray[obj.Children().Count()];
            //fill the array with the children of obj => results[6] = "[{"show": {"title": "Game of Thrones", "imdb_id": "tt0944947", "epguide_name": "gameofthrones"}, "title": "TBA", "number": 1, "season": 7, "release_date": "2017-06-25"}]"
            for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
            {
                results[i] = (JArray)obj[(i + 1).ToString()];
            }
            //deserialize each item in results to List<Episode> if you checked the response it returns arrays of episodes
            List<List<Episode>> seasons = new List<List<Episode>>(results.Length);
            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                seasons.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Episode>>(item.ToString()));
            }
            //output the result
            foreach (var season in seasons)
            {
                foreach (var episod in season)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Show: {0}, release date: {1}", episod.show.title, episod.release_date);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```